# How to rewrite this nested query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is the syntax of this query

```
SELECT * FROM  table1
WHERE var_c IN(
SELECT var_a FROM table2 
WHERE var_b =55554444
);
```

Equivalent to this?

```
SELECT table1.* FROM table1, table2
WHERE (table2.var_a=table1.var_c AND table2.var_b=55554444);
```

The first one takes about 7-8 seconds to run and the 2nd one takes about .75 seconds to run.  When I use a Join statement it takes about 4-5 seconds to run.

Also is the syntax of this

```
DELETE FROM  table1
WHERE var_c IN(
SELECT var_a FROM table2 
WHERE var_b =55554444
);
```

And this:

```
DELETE table1.* FROM table1, table2
WHERE (table2.var_a=table1.var_c AND table2.var_b=55554444);
```

The same?

Comment: How many rows do the tables have? What datatypes are the columns? What indexes do you have?

Comment: Can you post the EXPLAIN of the 2 queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the 2 queries are not equivalent. The second can return duplicate rows, if `(var_a, var_b)` is not `UNIQUE` in `table2`

The first query though:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  table1
WHERE var_c IN
      ( SELECT var_a 
        FROM table2 
        WHERE var_b =55554444
      )
```

and if `table2.var_a` does not contain any `NULL` values, then it's equivalent to this:

```
SELECT table1.* 
FROM table1
   , table2
WHERE table2.var_a = table1.var_c 
  AND table2.var_b = 55554444
GROUP BY table1.PK                --- Primary Key of table1
```

(which is better to be written with explicit `JOIN` syntax as:

```
SELECT table1.* 
FROM table1
  JOIN table2
    ON table2.var_a = table1.var_c 
WHERE table2.var_b = 55554444
GROUP BY table1.PK                --- Primary Key of table1
```

and this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  table1
WHERE EXISTS 
      ( SELECT *
        FROM table2 
        WHERE table2.var_b = 55554444
          AND table2.var_a = table1.var_c
      )
```

---

About performance, the best advice you could get is to test, test and test again with your data. Try with different indexes and figure how to read the EXPLAIN plans.

You'll probably find that `IN (SELECT ... FROM ...)` has not the best performance with current MySQL optimizer (although I hear that MariaDB plans some major improvements in next release, Maria 5.3) and that `JOIN` and `EXISTS` variants perform usually better.

But this heavily depends on the indexes you have on the tables. Without any index, all of them will be slow. And `query time < 1 sec` does not mean it's fast. With a billion rows in the tables, yes, it's pretty good. For a table with only a few thousand rows, `time < 0.01 sec` should be expected.

Comment: +1 you are entirely correct, as I edited in my answer. The "correct" query depends on whether OP wants possible duplications from the `JOIN` but the explicit `JOIN` as you and I both noted is preferable to his syntax (though his may get converted by the RDBMS)

Comment: Also, ypercube, why is it better to use JOIN syntax `ON table2.var_a = table1.var_c` as opposed to `WHERE table2.var_a = table1.var_c`?

Comment: It's more readable, especially if you have a lot of joins. It's easy to forget to write a condition on the `WHERE` when joining 10 tables. Also, it's needed when you want `LEFT` or `RIGHT` outer joins.

Comment: Plus, it's in the SQL-92 standard (almost 20 years old now!)

Comment: Another thing that is a limitation of the implicit join with `WHERE` is that essentially (as @Matthew had in his answer) a `FROM tablea, b, c, ..., z WHERE a.id = b.id AND ... y.ff = z.ff` is a `CROSS JOIN` of 2 or more tables with some conditions applied (not that this is how SQL-products implement it).

Comment: With the explicit join syntax, you can have `FROM (a JOIN b) JOIN c` or `FROM a JOIN (b JOIN c)` or `FROM (a JOIN b) LEFT JOIN c`, etc. More flexibility.

Comment: Thanks so much, you've really helped me learn some important concepts.

Comment: @LedZeppelin I deleted my answer  because It was fundamentally incorrect for the question. While I wanted you to correct your `JOIN` syntax for *what I thought* you wanted to do... My answer to the actual question of whether the queries are equivalent was incorrect. While they both accomplished the same goal in your case, and should have been formatted differently, there are subtle differences between them which ypercube has pointed out in his answer. Ypercube's answer is correct and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an [inner join](http://mysqljoin.com/joins/inner-join-tutorial/):

```
SELECT * FROM  table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table2.var_a = table1.var_c
WHERE table2.var_b =55554444
```

Comment: Hmm, joins shouldn't be slow. I have done triple joins on tables having more than 80,000 rows each. Check the structure of your database, and make sure the query doesn't return duplicate rows

Comment: Comment removed, I was returning the results of a different table using the join statement.  That's why it took like 5 seconds.  When I tried it on the table I'm talking about in this example it took <1sec

Answer (score 1):

This query is invalid `DELETE * FROM  table1`, use `DELETE FROM table1`